# Two functions run on the same org-export filter; first has no effect

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I'm passing more than one headline filter function to a `BIND` inside my org file, and I can't see why only the second seems to have an impact:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :exports results :results none
  (defun tmp-f-list-singlebreak (s backend info)
    (message "list singlebreak!")
    (when (eq backend 'ascii)
      (when (string-match-p "^* " s)
        (message "match * in singlebreak")
        (replace-regexp-in-string "\n\n" "\n" s))
      (when (string-match-p "^◊ " s)
        (message "match ◊ in singlebreak")
        (replace-regexp-in-string "\n\n" "\n" s))))
  (defun tmp-f-list-item-better-bullet (s backend info)
    (message "bullet!")
    (when (eq backend 'ascii)
      (replace-regexp-in-string "^◊ " "• " s)
    ))
#+END_SRC
#+BIND: org-export-filter-headline-functions (tmp-f-list-singlebreak tmp-f-list-item-better-bullet)
```

The messages printed are:

```
list singlebreak!
match ◊ in singlebreak
bullet!
list singlebreak!
match ◊ in singlebreak
bullet!
list singlebreak!
bullet!
```

From which it is clear that both functions are running. However the results on these exported items make it seem like `tmp-f-list-singlebreak` is not working:

```
** Heading
*** item one
*** item two
```

is exported as:

```
Heading
═══════


• item one

• item two
```

... when I expect there to not be a line break between `item one` and `item two`.

Comment: The obvious suspects are those `replace-regexp-in-string`: maybe they don't work the way you expect. I would test them separately: define a string `s` with (part) of the exported output and then pass it through eacho `replace-regexp-in-string` to see what happens.

Comment: Are you sure that the output you are showing corresponds to the Org mode file you show? There are no `diamond` characters in the input, but the messages show that  "^◊ " matched - how can that be?

Comment: @NickD yes definitely. When I use org-export-dispatch to export to UTF8 , the export turns `*` into `◊` for the bullets.

Comment: Who does that? I don't see anything in the above that turns `*` into `◊` and nothing in my experiments does anything to disprove that. Do you have some *other* setup that perhaps does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simplified function:

```el
  (defun tmp-f-list-singlebreak (s backend info)
    (message s)
    (when (eq backend 'ascii)
      (replace-regexp-in-string "\n\n" "\n" s)))
```

The filters are applied *after* the headline is "transcoded", i.e. after the exporter is done with it: at that point, there are not stars left to match, so I doubt you are doing the `replace-regexp-in-string` at all.

Note also that the above prints the incoming string for debugging. That allows you to check that indeed there is no asterisk left, so the `string-match-p` calls prevent the function from doing anything.

If you want better debugging messages, you can use `format`:

```el
...
(message (format "In singlebreak: %s" s))
...
```

EDIT: The OP must have some setting to "beautify" the asterisks in the headline, which is probably why `◊` characters appear in the export output. When I run the exporter `text->UTF8` on his example Org mode file (with the "better debugging messages" method above), I get the following debugging output in `*Messages*`:

```
singlebreak: 1.1 item one
────────────

 [2 times]
bullet: 1.1 item one
────────────
 [2 times]
singlebreak: 1.2 item two
────────────

 [2 times]
bullet: 1.2 item two
────────────
 [2 times]
singlebreak: 1 Heading
═════════

1.1 item one
────────────

1.2 item two
────────────

 [2 times]
bullet: 1 Heading
═════════
1.1 item one
────────────
1.2 item two
────────────
 [2 times]
```

No asterisks and no diamonds.

Comment: Your code fixes the issue although your explanation does not match the result. The branching logic definitely matched the input: the exporter turns `*` to `◊` and then the `when` matched (proven by debugging output)... So it seems like the return value inside the conditionals was being discarded for some (probably basic lisp?) reason. Nonetheless, thanks for your help, I am grateful that it works now.

Comment: How does the exporter turn `*` into `◊`?

Comment: I don't know, that's just the result I choose export to text->utf8 in org-export-dispatch: `*` in my org mode turns into `◊`.

Comment: That's not standard: something in your init file does that. You can verify by starting emacs with `-q` which will bypass your init file. If you identify the culprit, add that information either in a comment here or (better) to your question, it'll be easy to figure out what's happening.